# Too much line spacing when adding text to document programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to insert text from a .txt-file into a document (using Apps Script, of course), but I end up with a completely misformatted document because Apps Script seems to set a line spacing that's bigger than usual.

I've tried using setLineSpacing on the paragraph I'm adding the text to, but it still doesn't look like when I'm adding the text to the document manually. Changing the line spacing in Google Docs didn't help either (same result).

Here's a sample file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ahBlVgZTmln3QIj8tUdvzHn56JS2VnjTLsPcoSOZA7I/edit?usp=sharing

The first two lines have been added by Apps Script, the latter two lines have been added by myself using Google Docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while writing this question I was able to answer the question myself: call `setSpacingAfter(0)` on the paragraph you're adding to the document and everything is fine.

I don't understand why Apps Script behaves like that out-of-the-box...